# PLSQL looping through JSON object

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Basically I have a json that looks like this [{"group":"groupa","status":"active"},{"group":"groupb","status":"inactive"}] and I want to loop through and extract the **group** only and save them in a variable in order to loop and compare the groups to a certain variable.

for example

```
group := 'groupc'
while counter < jsonGroup.count
loop
if jsonGroup(counter) := group then ....
```

is there any way to save the group into jsonGroup as an array or table?

thank you

Comment: Is this JSON in a table column? You would need to select the data into a cursor and loop through the cursor until you reach the end of the data. There won't be a `jsonGroup.count` property; that isn't how SQL works. It isn't object-oriented. If possible, always try to think in terms of batch SQL operations and not loops, too. Loops will _always_ be slower by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use JSON PL/SQL object types to iterate over the JSON array and to extract the value of the `group` attribute of the objects:

```sql
DECLARE
  value VARCHAR2(4000) := '[{"group":"groupa","status":"active"},{"group":"groupb","status":"inactive"}]';
  ja JSON_ARRAY_T := JSON_ARRAY_T.PARSE(value);
  je JSON_ELEMENT_T;
  grp VARCHAR2(20);
  i  PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    je := ja.GET(i);
    EXIT WHEN je IS NULL;
    grp := TREAT(je AS JSON_OBJECT_T).get_string('group');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(grp);
    i := i + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> groupa
> groupb
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The values can be stored into an array using the `JSON_ARRAY_T` functionality as MT0 described or using `JSON_TABLE` which might be better if your JSON is already stored in a table.

Below is an example of how to use both methods to store the groups into an array.

```sql
DECLARE
    l_json_text   VARCHAR2 (100)
        := '[{"group":"groupa","status":"active"},{"group":"groupb","status":"inactive"}]';

    TYPE tab_t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (100);

    l_table       tab_t := tab_t ();
    l_array       json_array_t;

    PROCEDURE print_tab
    IS
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1 .. l_table.COUNT
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_table (i));
        END LOOP;
    END;
BEGIN
    l_array := json_array_t (l_json_text);

    l_table.EXTEND (l_array.get_size);

    FOR i IN 1 .. l_array.get_size
    LOOP
        l_table (i) := TREAT (l_array.get (i - 1) AS json_object_t).get_string ('group');
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('After JSON_ARRAY_T method');
    print_tab;

    l_table.delete;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('After delete');
    print_tab;

    SELECT grp
      BULK COLLECT INTO l_table
      FROM JSON_TABLE (l_json_text, '$[*]' COLUMNS grp PATH '$.group');

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('After JSON_TABLE method');
    print_tab;
END;
/
```